# How to share cache on gitlab-runner when concurrent jobs

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a code that I test using gitlab-ci.
Previously, I was using a shared gitlab-runner, and everything was fine.

I recently migrated to a gitlab-runner hosted by my company, and the exact same code is no longer valid through the gitlab-ci pipeline.
The error raised was:

```
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script 00:05
Using docker image sha256:xxx for registry.gitlab.com/me/myproject/myimage with digest registry.gitlab.com/me/myproject/myimage@sha256:xxx ...
$ cd build
/bin/bash: line 125: cd: build: No such file or directory
```

I investigate and found a problem about the cache shared.
Indeed, my cache is shared between different jobs working concurrently at the same stage, but on shared runner freely available it was not an issue.
So, I switch my gitlab-runner configuration in order to have no concurrent jobs (ie. `concurrent = 1` in the file `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`), resulting no cache problem anymore.
I conclude that the issue is more about the gitlab-runner configuration.
My current configuration file `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` is:

```
concurrent = 8
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
name = "MY-RUNNER-NAME"
url = "https://gitlab.com/"
token = "MY-TOKEN"
executor = "docker"
[runners.custom_build_dir]
[runners.cache]
   Shared = true
   [runners.cache.s3]
   [runners.cache.gcs]
   [runners.cache.azure]
[runners.docker]
   tls_verify = false
   image = "IMAGE:latest"
   privileged = true
   disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
   oom_kill_disable = false
   disable_cache = false
   volumes = ["/cache"]
   shm_size = 0
```

So how to configure my runner to allow concurrent jobs to share their caches (or solve this conflict) ?

## EDIT

Here is my `gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
# GitLab-CI configuration file.

stages:
  - prepare
  - build
  - test

.allConfigs:
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - DISTRIBUTION: ['alpine']
        COMPILER: ['gcc'] 
  image: ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/${DISTRIBUTION}-${COMPILER}
  cache:
    key: ${DISTRIBUTION}-${COMPILER}-key
    paths:
      - build/
      - external/
  

prepare:
  stage: prepare
  script:
    - git reset --hard HEAD 
    - git clean -d -f -x
    - mkdir build
    - cd build
    - cmake ../
    - make update
  extends: .allConfigs


build-exe:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd build
    - cmake ../ #-DTESTING=OFF
    - make main
    - make install
  extends: .allConfigs


test-integration:
  stage: test
  script:
    - cd build
    - cmake ../ -DTESTING=ON
    - make integrationTest
  extends: .allConfigs
  
test-unit:
  stage: test
  script:
    - cd build
    - cmake ../ -DTESTING=ON
    - make unitTest
  extends: .allConfigs
```

The error mentioned appears when the 2 test jobs are executing concurrently.

Comment: Is it the same runner that you are using? If yes, then you should take a look at this https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#use-the-same-cache-for-all-branches

Comment: @ArihantGodha Yes I am using the same runner. I looked at your suggested documentation. However, I don't see how it solves my problem. This is more about the gitlab-ci configuration (caches etc). While, my `gitlab-ci.yml` (unchanged) was working on the previous runner. So, caches should be ok. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: Could you update your post with more of your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file? My guess is that you're relying on the cache 100% without a way to regenerate the cached objects. When using the cache, you should always have a way to generate the things you need in the event that the cache isn't present for any reason. The docs [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#availability-of-the-cache) say: "Caching is an optimization, but it isn’t guaranteed to always work. You might need to regenerate cached files in each job that needs them."

Comment: @AdamMarshall I have updated my question. I am not sure to understand completely why the caching is not guaranteed. So yes, I can rebuild my project's cache in every job but I will then lose a lot of gitlab-ci time and optimization. But of course, if there is no choice I will do it.

Comment: It's more that in each job you should check if it exists and use it if so, but create it (and re-cache it) if not. Unless you use a distributed cache (https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnerscache-section), the cache only lives on a single runner, and is not shared between runners. If your job is picked up on a different runner, your cache won't exist so you'll have to create it again.

Comment: @AdamMarshall To be sure to understand correctly your purpose, you are suggesting that despite the option `[runners.cache] Shared=True` , the cache is not distributed unless I use another specific cache server (that need to be installed). So the solution left if there is no cache server is to re-build (ie. re-cache) when jobs are concurrent.

Comment: Yea, the `shared` attribute won’t do anything unless you’re using a distributed caching service, but it exists since perhaps you don’t want to share it between runners, but can’t or don’t want to store it on the runner itself. To share between runners you’ll need a service like S3, Minio, Azure, etc (options in the docs above) and set `shared` to true. Even if you do this though, you should include a way to generate the things you need in your jobs.

Comment: @AdamMarshall Thanks for this precision. I think you can turn your comments into an answer.